# Find and Click button with JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a chrome extension (shortkeys) to create shortcut keys that can press buttons within our warehouse management system (so they can be matched to barcodes).

One of the buttons has no ID, and once it has been clicked the button innertext changes.  Ideally I'd like the shortcut to work on either version of the button

It is either

```
<input type="submit" value="Create Shipment" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
```

or

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/Order/OrderDocumentP/15467" target="_blank">Print Label</a>
```

I then have another button to be assigned to a different shortcut key

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/Picking/DespatchOrder?OrderId=13413">Despatch</a>
```

But I'm sure once I've figured out the first one the next will be easier :)

Any help greatly appreciated, I've been through a number of other questions that are similar but not quite what I'm after and my JS knowledge is pretty rubbish

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple script on getting a button by class name and clicking it. I think this is what you are looking for, if not let me know I will rewrite it.

EDIT: I added a loop that will click all buttons or links found with the class name `btn-success`

I've inserted a second function so people looking for a solution by classname can also still find the first one. `AutoClickBtnByValue()` will click the button with inner text "click me now".

```js
function AutoClickBtn() {
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-success");
  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].click();
    console.log('Success! Clicked button' + i);
  }
}
setInterval(AutoClickBtn, 2000);

/* Click button by innerHTML text */
function AutoClickBtnByValue() {
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-success");
  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    if (button[i].innerHTML.indexOf('click me now') > -1) {
      button[i].click();
      console.log('Success! Clicked button' + i + ' with value: "click me now" ');
    }
  }
}
setInterval(AutoClickBtnByValue, 2000);
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Create Shipment" class="btn btn-success pull-right">

<a class="btn btn-success" href="#" target="_blank">Print Label</a>

<a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Despatch</a>


<button class="btn-success">click me now</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that isn't quite what I was after though.

I wanted to find the button based on its inner text rather than the class please (as there are other buttons on the page with the same class).  

Thank you, appreciate your time having a look at this :)

Comment: That is still a possibility! I will see what I can do for ya

Comment: Current solution with `.innerHTML` works for `a` tags and `buttons` however if you wan to do it for input fields, use `.value`

Comment: Got it thanks, I used a single line for one of them

`document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-success pull-right')[0].click();`

And then your /* Click button by innerHTML text */

Comment: Great, If this helped you make sure to select the answer as the solution so other people facing the same issues as you will be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Learn CSS a bit and use https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Your extensions probaply supports that

```
// cuz I don't like to type long "document.querySelector"
q = sel => document.querySelector(sel)
qq = sel => document.querySelectorAll(sel)
function clickOnly(sel) {
   let list = qq(sel);
   if (list.length == 1) list[0].click();
   else alert('element "'+sel+'" is not unique!');
}

// handles *any* keypress
onkeypress = function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == "INPUT") return; // noop on input focused
  if (event.target.tagName == "TEXTAREA") return; // noop on input focused
  console.log(event.code); // to see what the key is
  let rawCode = event.code; // keyboard key, `KeyM` for M, `Digit7` for 7, `Slash` for /
  let code = rawCode; // make CtrlAltShiftKeyM
  if (event.shiftKey) code = 'Shift' + code;
  if (event.altKey) code = 'Alt' + code;
  if (event.ctrlKey) code = 'Ctrl' + code;
  if (!kds[event.code]) return;
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent CtrlKeyM browser handler for bookmarks or whatever
  kds[event.code](event);
}

kds = {}
// it's a function so starts with `() => `
kds.KeyM = () => alert('it works!')
// a is for <a>, [href^=] is for href starts with
kds.ShiftKeyM = () => clickOnly('a[href^="/Order/OrderDocumentP/]')
// , is for one of multiple selectors
kds.CtrlKeyM = () => clickOnly('input[value="Create Shipment"], a[href^="/Order/OrderDocumentP/]')
```